# The method Path.Line.translate() does not update the segments of the path

Tags: paperjs

I am working on a project using paper.js (0.11.8) and I am trying to move a single Path.Line using the provided translate() method. Although the line is moved on the canvas as expected, its segments (e.g. firstSegment.point) are not updated whereas the position is set correctly. Is this a bug or a feature? ;)

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a code example allowing us to reproduce the unexpected behaviour ? Look at this [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/rZDBCoMwDIZfJfQyx6To1bE32GHgUT1Ul2qxNqMt20B899VuYydvOyTw/Qn5fzIzIyZkBStH9N3AUtbRdeW7sKCVQTiBwQdchB/4OXAyg7Q0FVDlWQp51qTgKdIbYdkfa1ubtToyjjRyTX2ya1GSRfBWGKeFV2TSaMClss6X2E9oPL+RCv0ZXHdw2J7/POLK9ygmnxjZRgghPdq/Zggfay2KMYqOFVWzvAA=) which seems to be working as expected.

Comment: You are right, it does work as expected. There must be another problem in my code. Thanks.